# Difference in OpenSSL pkcs8 key generation

Tags: openssl, ecc

I came across two ways of generating an ECC private key. Both create the key in pkcs8 format.
Only the 2nd variant results in a pkcs8 file that contains the eccPublicKey OID `1.2.840.10045.2.1`.
Why do these two ways of generating the pkcs8 file differ?

```
1.
openssl ecparam -genkey -name brainpoolP256r1 -out key.pkcs8 -noout -outform der -param_enc explicit

2.
openssl ecparam -genkey -name brainpoolP256r1 -out key.pem -param_enc explicit
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in terminal.pem -outform DER -out key.pkcs8
del key.pem
```

Comment: **`ecparam -genkey` does NOT output PKCS8 format.** It outputs SEC1 format (see rfc5915) -- in either PEM or DER, although PEM has labels `BEGIN/END EC PRIVATE KEY` that make obvious it isn't PKCS8, see rfc7468.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 , exactly the info I needed.